Update whole column while inserting Row Python and Sqlite
I'm trying to write a FLASK page that a user can add a row and it will renumber all the preceding rows. For example (User inputs "2" and "2" exists rename "2" to "3", "3", to "4", and onward.
I have it working for the initial input but I can't figure out where to go from here:
   connection = sqlite3.connect('database')
   connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   cursor.execute("SELECT SCENE FROM main")
   scenelist = cursor.fetchall()
   for oldscene in scenelist:
      if oldscene['SCENE'] == int(scene):
         newscene = (oldscene['SCENE'] + 1)
         cursor.execute("UPDATE MAIN SET SCENE = ? WHERE SCENE = ?", (newscene, scene))
   cursor.execute("INSERT into MAIN (TITLE, LOCATION, CHAPTER, SCENE, TAGS) \
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (title, location, chapter, scene, tags,))


You want UPDATE main SET scene = scene + 1 WHERE scene >= ?.

"preceding" should be "succeeding"
